# SAS - Sort Multiple Dataset using loops

Tags: sas

I have a list of SAS datasets which I want to sort by the same variable.

I do not want to use the PROC Sort statement for each one of them,
is there a way to use loops to shorten the entire code?

I am new to SAS so please help!

```
%let prim =sasdata.qc_no_rx ;
%let other_removals = sasdata.qc_other_removals;
%let drops =sasdata.droplist;


Array data_1(3) $ sasdata.qc_no_rx sasdata.qc_other_removals 

sasdata.droplist ; 

do over data_1;
Proc sort data = data_1 ;
by ims_ref;
end;
```

Comment: Post what you've tried please. More than likely you'll need to use a macro, so explain how your 'list of datasets' is stored, is it in a SAS table already? Or is it in a text file or in your head? Or is there a naming convention for them?

Comment: Yes it is in form of SAS data sets (not a text file), I want to sort all of them using Proc sort. i have around 10 data sets, so I have to write 10 Proc sort statements (one for each dataset). I want to use loop instead..

Comment: Post what you've tried or at least your current code.

Comment: %let prim =sasdata.qc_no_rx ;
%let other_removals = sasdata.qc_other_removals;
%let drops =sasdata.droplist;
 

Array data_1(3) $ sasdata.qc_no_rx sasdata.qc_other_removals sasdata.droplist ; 
do over data_1;
Proc sort data = data_1 ;
by ims_ref;
end;

Comment: i have tried to use a proc sort statement inside a do loop

Comment: Edit your question with code. Its not legible in comments. Look into call execute - the documentation has an example.

Comment: @Rohit Goel You can always create a macro for this kind of repetitive job. If you can use proc sort that is!

Comment: @GauravTaneja Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a data set, called dname_list, with the data set names, and they're called dname. `Call execute` will generate the code and execute it.

I usually create my command in a string and then pass that to call execute. This is a `data _null_` step so it doesn't generate a data set but you can generate the data set to test at first if necessary.

You don't need to loop because SAS loops through the records in a data set by itself.

If you're sorting data in a library make sure to include the library name as well.

```
data _null_;
*data dname_execute;

set dname_list;
string = catt('proc sort data=', dname, '; by age; run;');
call execute(string);
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
%macro multsort(indlist,outdlist,byvarlist,ndata);
%do i = 1 %to &ndata.;

    %let indata = %scan("&indlist.",&i.,"   ");
    %let outdata = %scan("&outdlist.",&i.," ");
    %let byvars = %scan("&byvarlist.",&i.," ");
    proc sort data = &indata. out=&outdata.;by &byvars. ;run;
%end;
%mend;

%multsort(indlist=sashelp.Air   sashelp.Buy,outdlist=Sa Sb,byvarlist=Air    amount,ndata=2);
```

Comment: What are the quotes for?  I guess you could use the quotes in the delimiters list for the %SCAN() function so that you can get the macro code to see the space without having to use %STR( ), but why did you also put them around the list of names?

Comment: That is because I am passing unquoted text to the macro, the quotes will end up resolving `outdlist` as `"Sa Sb"` , without quotes it would just be `Sa Sb`.

Comment: Macro code treats quotes the same as any other characters. So if you take the first item from the space delimited list `"Sa Sb" ` the result will be `"Sa` instead of the desired `Sa`.  Your code only works because you also are telling `%SCAN()` to treat `"` as a delimiter and it skips any delimiters at the beginning of the list when looking for the first item.